# auto increment a property google app engine except sharding counters

Tags: google-app-engine, auto-increment

I am looking for a way to do auto increment of a property in Google App Engine . I am looking for something which comes from database and not some logical manipulations like sharding counters

Comment: What data storage option are you using?

Comment: Doesn't exist if your using the Datastore given your restrictions.

Comment: data storage option is High Replication

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query before you insert to find out the highest ID. The read and the write should be in a transaction so there won't be any race condition.

Of course, needless to say, this can be very inefficient at some point